# How to add focus and hover effect with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have html code as follows:

```
<div class="form-group g-mb-30">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input id="contact-email"
               class="form-control"
               type="email" placeholder="Email *" style="border-radius: 0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to add `hover` and `focus` effect with jquery.

The css that i have is as follows:

```
.g-state-hover > div span, .g-state-hover input, .g-state-focus > div span, .g-state-focus input{
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

And jquery for hover is as follows:

```
$(".input-group").hover(function (e) {
    $(this).addClass("g-state-hover");
}, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("g-state-hover");
});
```

And it works, but I want to do the same on focus.

Thus I want that span with `.input-group-text` class and input with id `contact-email` get `border: 1px solid blue`

I tried with:

```
$("#contact-email").focusin(function (e) {
    $(".input-group").addClass("g-state-focus");
});

$("#contact-email").focusout(function (e) {
    $(".input-group").removeClass("g-state-focus");
});
```

But nothing happens.

Any idea?

Comment: it looks like it works:https://jsfiddle.net/rquy4fwn/  or I do not get you well

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
`$("#contact-email").focusin(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().addClass("g-state-focus");
});`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".input-group").hover(function (e) {
        $(this).addClass("g-state-hover");
    }, function () {
        $(this).removeClass("g-state-hover");
    });
    $("#contact-email").focusin(function (e) {
        $(".input-group").addClass("g-state-hover");
    });

    $("#contact-email").focusout(function (e) {
        $(".input-group").removeClass("g-state-hover");
    });
});
```

```css
.g-state-hover > div span, .g-state-hover input, .g-state-focus > div span, .g-state-focus input{
  border: 1px solid blue;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
  -moz-box-shadow: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group g-mb-30">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input id="contact-email"
               class="form-control"
               type="email" placeholder="Email *" style="border-radius: 0;">
    </div>
</div>
```

Remove the `box-shadow` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is running Example When load page focus in your contact-email After you can check hover in out

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group g-mb-30">
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
        </div>
        <input id="contact-email"
               class="form-control"
               type="email" placeholder="Email *" style="border-radius: 0;">
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#contact-email").focus();
    $("#contact-email").hover(function(){

        $(this).css('background','red');

    },function(){
        $(this).css('background','white');


    })


})

</script>
```